# Return selected for select control after value comparison

Tags: php

I am trying to remove as much code from within my html as possible without using a template framework and I am unsure why `'selected'` is not being returned to define `'selected'` for the options of a select box. `$row_status` populates the options ok and `$status` has a value assigned.

Am I way off on this?

```
    <select id='status'>
     <option>Please Select</option>
     <?php while($row_status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results_status)): ?>
     <option <?php sel($row_status['list_value'],$status)?> >  <?php echo $row_status['list_value'] ?>  </option>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>

    function sel($rs, $status){
       if ($rs==$status){
          return "selected";
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only returning a value, not echoing it.

```
<?php echo sel(...); ?>
```

should work for you. You also might want to change your function to return an empty string in case the condition is not true.

```
function sel($rs, $status) {
    return ($rs == $status) ? "selected" : "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using `sprintf()` and passing the conditions and values via its arguments:

```
while ($row_status = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results_status)) {
    echo sprintf('<option%s>%s</option>',
        $row_status['list_value'] == $status ? ' selected' : '',
        htmlspecialchars($row_status['list_value'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
    );
}
```

I've added the proper HTML escaping as well.

Comment: Great feedback, thanks. doesn't using sprintf() alternative muddy the waters when trying to keep html and php blocks of code separate? I know this subject everyone has there 'personal' preference  if and when to template, I decided to hit the middle ground by using php tags around everything.....even though it is unlikly anyone else will be doing design work.....but keeping in mind I do not know exactly what my design will be! Thx

Comment: I think clarity in code should be the guiding principle. If your designer needs to understand the HTML I would opt for a template engine such as PHPTAL.